# How to group by a portion of a field (host) in a splunk mstats command

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

How can I group by a portion of a field in a Splunk `mstats` command? For example, I can get the environment from the host field using `eval`, but eval can't come before the `mstats` command, so it's not available in the `BY` clause.

````
| mstats sum(s3-worker.ndjson.aggregation) AS aggregations
    WHERE index="service_metrics" 
      AND result=success
      AND host=my-worker-*-aggregator*
    earliest=-2h
    BY result ```<-- Would like to add "env" here```
    span=1h
| eval env = replace(host, "^my-worker-(?<env>[^-]+)-aggregator.*$", "\1")
| eval active = IF(aggregations > 0, true, false)
````

Comment: The `*stats` commands cannot group results by a field that doesn't exist.  Even if you were to use a subsearch to extract `env` from `host`, `mstats` you would have a field value and not a field name.